# Where is sys/stat.h located in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and I used to see #include , I want to see the implementation code of `sys/stat.h`. But I don not know where it is. By the way, I can not find it in `/usr/include` directory.

Comment: `echo '#include <sys/stat.h>' | cc -E - | grep '^# '` will get you all the includes that are pulled in by `sys/stat.h`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

on my machine there are

```
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h
    /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/sys/stat.h
```

I think the first one is what you are looking for? it comes with gnu gcc I think

Comment: Thanks, I found in the first directory,thanks very much

Comment: if so, mark my answer or vote on it